# Update Messages List By OpenXML in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a list of messages with xml format, I want to send message ID to stored procedure using OpenXML update their status to 'A' status. You can see coding here as follows:

XML sample format:

```
 <Message>
    <MessageID>17</MessageID>
    <MessageID>16</MessageID>
    <MessageID>15</MessageID>
 </Message>
```

In stored procedure:

```
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @XmlMessagesItems
```

Way 1:

```
UPDATE SECMSG_TO   
SET SECMSG_TO.Status='A'
FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/Message',2) 
     with ( MessageID INT) ox  
WHERE  
    SECMSG_TO.MessageID = ox.MessageID
```

or way 2:

```
  UPDATE SECMSG_TO   
  SET SECMSG_TO.Status = 'A'
  WHERE SECMSG_TO.MessageID IN (SELECT *  
                                FROM OPENXML  (@idoc, '/Message',2) 
                                WITH ( MessageID INT)        
                            )
```

But by both ways I just can update first message means number 17 and other have not effected. Could you give me a clue how can I update all list completely.

Thanks.

Comment: What database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems - it's not a product... stuff like XML support is very vendor-specific, so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving a list of `Message` nodes where you need a list of `MessageID` nodes.

```
SELECT MessageID  
FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/Message/MessageID',2) 
WITH (MessageID INT '.')
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, but by previous method just first message would be updated and now none of them have been updated, could you let me know which part of process has problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
First Way: XML Format
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <Messages>
    <Message MessageID='33' />
    <Message MessageID='34' />
    <Message MessageID='20' />   
  </Messages>

 in Stored Procedure
  @XmlMessagesItems text
  DECLARE @idoc INT
  EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @XmlMessagesItems  
  UPDATE TableName   SET Status='A'
              from OPENXML  (@idoc, '/Messages/Message',1) 
              with ( MessageID INT) ox  
              WHERE MessageID = ox.MessageID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  XML Format
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <Messages>
    <Message MessageID='33' />
    <Message MessageID='34' />
    <Message MessageID='20' />   
  </Messages>

 in Stored Procedure
  UPDATE TableName   SET Status='A'          
     WHERE MessageID IN
     (
           select *  from OPENXML  (@idoc, '/Messages/Message',1) with ( MessageID INT )        
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 XML Format
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <Messages>
    <Message MessageID='33' />
    <Message MessageID='34' />
    <Message MessageID='20' />   
  </Messages>

    in Stored Procedure
    SELECT @MessageID = MessageID      
    FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/Messages/Message', 1)             
     WITH       
     (             
         MessageID   int 
     )        

     UPDATE TableName SET Status='A'     
         WHERE MessageID = @MessageID
```